# How to store data in a matrix

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I have a simple question: I created a function called se.bootstrap that receives elements from two vectors:

```
bs <- c(10, 25, 200, 500, 5000) 
sample.size <- c(5, 10, 200, 2000)
```

I am trying to pass all the possible combinations of the elements of these two vectors to this function and store the results in a matrix, such as:

```
      10                 25        200         500          5000
5     sd.boostrap(5, 10)
10
200
2000                                                       sd.boostrap(2000, 5000)
```

Could anyone help with that?
Thank you very much

Comment: what do you expect to get?

Comment: `sd.bootstrap` would be useful as well

Answer (score 0):

```
se.bootstrap  <- function(a,b) ( a*b)  # use whatever function on 2 variables
bs <- c(10, 25, 200, 500, 5000)    # your vectors
sample.size <- c(5, 10, 200, 2000) # your vectors
res  <- matrix(se.bootstrap(expand.grid(bs,sample.size)$Var1,expand.grid(bs,sample.size)$Var2),nrow = length(bs),ncol = length(sample.size))
```

expand.grid does what you want and returns Var1 and Var2 which goes to the function defined. 
the matrix() makes the vector a matrix having the dimensions of the vectors (you can switch cols=>rows)

```
res
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,]    50   100 2e+03 2e+04
[2,]   125   250 5e+03 5e+04
[3,]  1000  2000 4e+04 4e+05
[4,]  2500  5000 1e+05 1e+06
[5,] 25000 50000 1e+06 1e+07
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `se.bootstrap` returns a scalar, you can:

```
# function that returns a scalar
sd.fake <- function(bs, ss) bs*ss

# we prepare the matrix
res <- matrix(nr=length(sample.size), nc=length(bs), dimnames=list(sample.size, bs))

# we loop and fill the matrix
for (i in seq_along(sample.size))
  for (j in seq_along(bs))
    res[i, j] <- sd.fake(sample.size[i], bs[j])

> res
10    25   200     500    5000
5       50   125 1e+03    2500 2.5e+04
10     100   250 2e+03    5000 5.0e+04
200   2000  5000 4e+04  100000 1.0e+06
2000 20000 50000 4e+05 1000000 1.0e+07
```

Is this what you want? `expand.grid` may help as well.

Comment: @Zahiro Mor option is vectorized and probably a better option